# Definite integral substitution question.

Tags: definite-integrals, improper-integrals

Let's say you have
$$\int^\infty_0 f(x) dx$$
and you substitute $x=u^2$ so that the integral becomes,
$$\int^\infty_0 f(u) du$$ 
or
$$\int^{-\infty}_0 f(u) du$$

My question is, which of these integral intervals are valid? Are they both always valid or are there cases when only one of them or none of them are valid? And if there are such cases how do I determine when that is the case?

Edit:

The integral in question is:
$$\int^{\infty}_0 e^xx^{y-1}dx, \space\space\space y>0$$
I did this substitution:
$x=u^2$, because I wanted to arrive to this:
$$2\int^{\infty}_0 e^{u^2}u^{2y-1}du$$

So what would be a better substitution?

Comment: The substitution ought to be a bijective function.

Comment: If you substitute $x=u^2$ then the integral becomes $2\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\infty}uf(u^2) \ \mathrm{d}u$

Comment: @Novice so you mean my substitution is illegal?

Comment: In some sense yes. Because you have to take square roots and as what you have written, there are two cases. A positive and a negative one. If you are sure that after the transformation $u$ only assumes positive or negative values, then it is ok. Otherwise, try to at least use injective functions.

Comment: @Novice Would an example of an injective function be $x={|u|}^2$?

Comment: No. $|u|^2=u^2$.

Comment: Perhaps you can provide an example for the integral and we can see what transformations are applicable?

Comment: @Novice Would $|x|=u^2$ do then? I editted my question with the integral in question, aswell.

Comment: The substitution is right, but not in the sense of $x=u^2$ (Anyway, $|x|=x$ for this case since your $x\geq0$.) You should use $u=\sqrt{x}$, even though both are similar.

Comment: Then you will not run into the trouble of the $-\infty$

Comment: @Novice Thanks and also thanks for the terms bijective and injective that I didn't know existed.

Comment: You are welcome:)